# How do I make a working volume slider in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, media-player

I'm trying to make a volume slider that changes the volume of the player in QT but I can't get it to work.

This is a picture of my music player. Currently, when I slide the volume slider while music is playing, the volume does not change/update to the value of the slider.

[image]

These are snipets of the code I'm using for the volumeslider:

```
volumeSlider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal, this);
volumeSlider->setRange(0, 100);
volumeSlider->setFixedWidth(100);
volumeSlider->setValue(100);
player = new QMediaPlayer;
```

..

```
connect(volumeSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SIGNAL(volumeChanged(int)));
connect(volumeSlider, SIGNAL(volumeChanged(int)), player, SLOT(setVolume(int)));
```

..

```
    int MainWindow::volume() const
{
    return volumeSlider->value();
}


void MainWindow::setVolume(int volume)
{
    player->setVolume(volume);
}
```

Comment: Why not just connect `valueChanged(int)` to `setVolume(int)`?

Comment: Wow! It worked! I can't believe it. I was trying to figure this out for hours and it was as simple as this... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eh...I mean just one line

```
connect(volumeSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),player, SLOT(setVolume(int)));
```

and that's all you need to make it work.

---

Your original code:

```
connect(volumeSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SIGNAL(volumeChanged(int)));
connect(volumeSlider, SIGNAL(volumeChanged(int)), player, SLOT(setVolume(int)));  
      //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error here
```

is wrong because there is no `volumeChanged(int)` signal in `QSlider`, and there should be some notification about failed connection from Qt Creator as you compiled the code (shown in the console of Qt Creator).

I guess the `volumeChanged(int)` is a custom signal defined in the main widget, and if you change the original code to

```
connect(volumeSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SIGNAL(volumeChanged(int)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(volumeChanged(int)), player, SLOT(setVolume(int)));
     // ^^^^
```

and it should work because you connect A to B and then connect B to C, but it's verbose. Hence I asked you why not just connect A to C.

As for your last modification:

```
connect(volumeSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SIGNAL(volumeChanged(int))); // Does nothing
connect(volumeSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), player, SLOT(setVolume(int)));
```

It's like connect A to B, and connect A to C but only the connection of A to C works (mentioned above). The first connection is not necessary (since B is a `SIGNAL`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb, it was as simple as changing:

```
connect(volumeSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SIGNAL(volumeChanged(int)));
connect(volumeSlider, SIGNAL(volumeChanged(int)), player, SLOT(setVolume(int)));
```

to

```
connect(volumeSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SIGNAL(volumeChanged(int)));
connect(volumeSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), player, SLOT(setVolume(int)));
```

Thank you Tay2510:
"Why not just connect valueChanged(int) to setVolume(int)? –  Tay2510"